# how to get variable from different AngularJS file?

Tags: angularjs

How is it possible to get $scope variable from different file (with different module)? For example, I have two files - `index.js`  and `login.js`, I want to get username from `login.js` in `index.js`. I tried to use **services** but couldn't achieve that goal. The controller doesn't see service in another angular file.

Codes partially are given below:

```
bookApp.controller('bookListCtrl', ['sharedProperties', function($scope, $http, sharedProperties) {
'use strict';


$scope.name = "Alice";



console.log("in book controller");

console.log("getting login name: "+sharedProperties.getProperty());
```

and

```
var authentication = angular.module('authentication', []);


 authentication.service('sharedProperties', function () {
                  var property = 'First';

                  return {
                      getProperty: function () {
                          return property;
                      },
                      setProperty: function(value) {
                          property = value;
                      }
                  };
});
```

I got this exception -

> angular.min.js:63 Error: Unknown provider: authentication.sharedPropertiesProvider <- authentication.sharedProperties
>       at Error (native)
>       at

Comment: While declaring the other module, have you included a dependency to module "authentication"?

Comment: How are you including the authentication module in your main app? Don't forget you need to include it in your overall module. So your main app, needs to include "authentication" as a module.

Comment: @Sarathy I included the other module and got different exception. Currently, it doesn't recognize the service in "authentication" module and shows it as a "undefined".

Comment: Declaration of bookListCtrl seems wrong.  Try to use ['$scope', '$http', 'sharedProperties', function($scope, $http, sharedProperties) ...

Comment: @Sarathy thanks for this. It helped me

Comment: Glad it helped. I will add this as the answer. Please mark it as the answer,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 problems in the given implementation. The first problem is that the module 'authentication' needs to be a dependency for the consuming modules. The second problem is in the declaration of bookListCtrl. It needs to be defined as follows.

```
bookApp.controller('bookListCtrl', ['$scope','$http','sharedProperties', function($scope, $http, sharedProperties){
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you give an example how you've used services?

Normally if you define controllers like:

```
app.controller('LoginController', ['UserService', function($scope) {
   $scope.someMethod = function(){
       // push information to service
       UserService.username = $scope.username;
   }
}]);

app.controller('IndexController', ['UserService', function($scope) {
   // pull information from service
   $scope.username = UserService.username;
}]);
```

It should work. I must suggest you thou to use Controller as instead of $scope. More info here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController